# TortoiseCSV "nothing known" error based on user accounts?

Tags: cvs

When checking out or updating using TortoiseCVS from my repository, some user accounts get the "nothing known" error while some other accounts don't. The Symptom seems to be totally random. Has anyone seen anything like this before?

Server is a Debian Lenny

CVS server version: Concurrent Versions System (CVS) 1.12.13 (client/server)

TortoiseCVS version: 1.10.10

Answer (score 3):

It was caused by UNIX file permissions, it pretty much was the cvs's way of saying "Permission Denied"

All working now, in case anyone's looking for the solution for the same problem, check your file permissions.